# Negation of set statement

Tags: elementary-set-theory, propositional-calculus

What is the negation of the following statement?

$$B \subseteq A \Rightarrow C \subsetneq A$$

So far, I have:

$$B \subseteq A \land \neg (C \subsetneq A)$$

How do I simplify it further?

Comment: Um.. obviously $\not C \not \subset A $ is $C \subset A$.  So $B\subset A \land C \subset A$.

Comment: @fleablood; Assuming $\not C$ should actually have been $C$: $C\subsetneq A$ means "C is a proper subset of $A$" and is definitely *not* the same as $C\not\subset A$.

Comment: Oops... okay... so B is subset of A and C is not proper subset of A... hmmm...

Answer (score 1):

The expression $\neg(C\subsetneqq A)$ says that $C$ is not a proper subset of $A$. There are therefore two possibilities: either $C$ is not a subset of $A$ at all; or $C$ is a subset of $A$ but not a proper one, in which case $C=A$. Thus, the expression is equivalent to

$$C\nsubseteq A\lor C=A\;.$$

Your whole expression is therefore equivalent to

$$B\subseteq A\land\big(C\nsubseteq A\lor C=A\big)\;.\tag{1}$$

You can apply distributivity of $\land$ over $\lor$ to get

$$(B\subseteq A\land C\nsubseteq A)\lor B\subseteq A=C\;.$$

Whether either of these is actually simpler than $B\subseteq A\land\neg(C\subsetneqq A)$ is a matter of taste, opinion, and how you’re intending to use the expression; there isn’t any really nice equivalent expression. Expression $(1)$ is arguably the clearest, since it shows explicitly the two ways in which $C$ can fail to be a proper subset of $A$.

Answer (score 0):

[**Note**: Following comments, this answer assumes $\subsetneq$ means $\not\subseteq$, or *not a subset*. Apparently [$\subsetneq$](https://oeis.org/wiki/List_of_LaTeX_mathematical_symbols#Negated_binary_operators) is undefined.]

Let $P=B\subseteq A$ and $Q=C\subsetneq A$. Then the negation of $P\Rightarrow Q$ is $P\not\Rightarrow Q$, which is called [Material nonimplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_nonimplication), and has the logical equivalence $P\land \lnot Q$.

\begin{array} {c|c|c|c}
P&Q&P\Rightarrow Q&P\not\Rightarrow Q\\
\hline
T&T&T&F\\
T&F&F&T\\
F&T&T&F\\
F&F&T&F
\end{array}
In your case, $C \subsetneq A$ has the simple negation to $C \subseteq A$, so we arrive at:
$$B \subseteq A\land C \subseteq A\to B \cup C \subseteq A$$

Comment: "In your case, $C\subsetneq A$ has the simple negation to $C\subseteq A$," — You're not really claiming the negation of "$C$ is a proper subset of $A$" is "$C$ is a subset of $A$", are you?

Comment: $C\subsetneq A$ means C is not a subset of A, although I have seen the notation to mean a subset but not a proper one

Comment: I've never seen $C\subsetneq A$ to mean $C\not\subseteq A$. Can you point me to *any* source where this notation is used with that meaning?

Comment: I made the same conclusion but I believe $C \not \subset A$ is the accepted notation. $C \subsetneq A $ I believe means proper subset after all.  The latex is "subsetneq" for gosh sake.

Comment: proper subset is =

Comment: @JonMarkPerry: $C\subsetneq A$ emphatically does **not** mean that $C$ is not a subset of $A$; it means that $C$ is a proper subset of $A$. It is synonymous with $C\subsetneqq$.

Comment: @fleablood; i found [oeis;wiki](https://oeis.org/wiki/List_of_LaTeX_mathematical_symbols#Binary_operators) which has it as undefined, and the [MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) {12} is confusing to say the least - anyway i've edited my answer to reflect this discussion as i think my result is quite nice - tnx JMP

Comment: sorry last message should have gone to @celtschk; (probably did anyway but to be sure)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset